# Change eclipse's default launch configuration for all C/C++ projects

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

***Although there might be questions on SO that appear similar to this one I assure you that none of those have been able to answer mine.***

I've been figuring out a way to sort of "automate" (I guess you could say) my eclipse projects. To elaborate, let's say I create a C++ project in eclipse using the project creation dialog. This creates two (default) build configurations for the project (Debug and Release).

The annoyance I have run into is that when launching the project, every time I want to switch build configurations (i.e. Debug or Release) I have to manually change the path to the respective ".exe" in the project's launch config, which is rather cumbersome. (See image below...)

[image: Launch Config]

by replacing the "C/C++ Application" field with the following:

`${config_name:${project_name}}/${project_name}.exe`

The appropriate .exe is launched based on the currently active configuration. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Currently, however, I have to set the launch config this way for every C/C++ project I make since eclipse only generates a run configuration as seen in the image (which is not what I want). My question is, how can I make eclipse automatically produce this launch configuration for every C/C++ project I make?